# move duplicate items at the end of the array

Tags: array, go

> I have array [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4]  so I
> want to move all duplicates at the end of the array [1, 2, 3, 4,1, 2,
> 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4]. is there is another best way to do the same ***Go***
> Time O(n) and space O(1)

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    a := []int{1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4}
    key := make(map[int]bool)
    var original []int
    var duplicate []int
    for _, v := range a {
        if _, val := key[v]; !val {
            key[v] = true
            original = append(original, v)
        } else {
            duplicate = append(duplicate, v)
        }
    }
    fmt.Println(append(original, duplicate...))
}
```

Comment: But your solution is not `O(1)` space. You use additional memory for `key` map, and `original`/`duplicate` slices.

Comment: @demas I said is there any other way to do in space O(1). Please read my question

Comment: `Any other` means that you already have one solution and looking for `other`. Btw, you can decrease memory usage if you will use `map[int]int` where the `key` is a number in `a` and `value` is a number of occurrences this number in the `a`. And after that you can modify `a` in-place using this map.  In this case you still have `O(n)` in time and `O(uniq(n))` in space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your algorithm, there's some memory management tweaks to improve performance:

- `map[int]bool` can be replaced by `map[int]struct{}` - since only map-key lookup is needed to detect a duplicate
- if you know the output size of a slice before hand, you can pre-allocate the exact size and place values precisely in their various indices - avoiding reallocs with the built-in `append` function

---

```
func ver2(in []int) (out []int) {

    key := make(map[int]struct{}) // use an empty struct - key presence is all we need
    out = make([]int, len(in))    // pre-alloc output slice

    var dups []int

    j := 0
    for _, v := range in {
        if _, ok := key[v]; !ok {
            key[v] = struct{}{}
            out[j] = v
            j++
        } else {
            dups = append(dups, v)
        }
    }

    copy(out[j:], dups) // copy dups in place - rather than append
    return
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/5yiqe76Zgu9

Comment: Also if you don't care about the order of the duplicates, then they could be placed at the end of the slice working inward - and avoid the need for a `dups` slice.

Answer (score -1):

the full program available [here](https://play.golang.org/p/a8mCEj36ddR) outputs

```
            original []int{1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4}
         sorted orig []int{1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4}
             withMap []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4}
           withSlice []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 4, 4, 4}
            withBest []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 4, 4, 4}

            original []int{3, 5, 3, 4, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4}
         sorted orig []int{1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5}
             withMap []int{3, 5, 4, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4}
           withSlice []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4}
            withBest []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4}

            original []int{4, 3, 4, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4}
         sorted orig []int{1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4}
             withMap []int{4, 3, 1, 2, 4, 3, 3, 4}
           withSlice []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4}
            withBest []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4}

            original []int{100, 150, 400, 302, 450}
         sorted orig []int{100, 150, 302, 400, 450}
             withMap []int{100, 150, 400, 302, 450}
           withSlice []int{100, 150, 302, 400, 450}
            withBest []int{100, 150, 302, 400, 450}
```

It contains this function, which based on some conditions will make use of either a map based algorithm or a slice based algorithm.

```
func dedupBest(in []int) ([]int, int) {
    ln := len(in)
    if ln < 2 {
        return in, 1
    }
    min, max := minMax(in)
    if max < ln {
        // in-place.
        for i := 0; i < ln; i++ {
            v := in[i]
            for in[v] != v {
                in[v], in[i] = in[i], in[v]
                v = in[i]
            }
        }
        var e int
        for i := 0; i < ln; i++ {
            if i == in[i] {
                in[e], in[i] = in[i], in[e]
                if in[e] == max {
                    break
                }
                e++
            }
        }
        return in, e + 1
    }
    if (max-min)/ln >= 70 {
        return dedupWithMap(in)
    }
    // with alloc.
    tmp := make([]vl, max-min+1, max-min+1)
    for i := 0; i < ln; i++ {
        v := in[i]
        k := tmp[v-min]
        k.v = v
        k.c++
        tmp[v-min] = k
    }
    var e int
    for i := 0; i < len(tmp); i++ {
        k := tmp[i]
        if k.c > 0 {
            k.c--
            in[e] = k.v
            tmp[e] = k
            e++
        }
    }
    ee := e
    tmp = tmp[:e]
    for e < len(in) {
        for i := 0; i < len(tmp); i++ {
            k := tmp[i]
            for k.c > 0 {
                k.c--
                in[e] = k.v
                e++
            }
        }
    }
    return in, ee
}
```

It is faster when it can work without allocation when `max(list)` is smaller than `len(list)`. If, not, then a rapid estimation of the iteration cost is compared to a threshold to figure out which next algorithm should perform best.

When working in place it simply swaps values to their corresponding natural position, duplicated values ends up wherever space exists.
Then it iterates over all positions until `max(list)` is found to check if they belong to the current index, if not, the value is swapped to the end of the slice. This is fast when it does not have to  iterate up to `len(list)`

When it has to allocate, it attempts to be faster by reducing the number of iterations using `min` / `max`. The method is a bit different as it uses a struct to build the frequencies and that it outputs duplicated items in sorted order.

Also because it is a slice it does not require a bunch of allocations like a map can do when it has to grow.

The benchmark and tests available [here](https://play.golang.org/p/v8fRRLPWBRn) outputs (something like) those results.

In the benchmark the titles like `BenchmarkDedup/withMap____________1-1_________`, reads `../algorithm __vmax-len__`.

Where `vmax` and `len` controls the length of the input slices and the amplitude of its values. Then, `rand.Intn` is used to generate some sequence to dedup.

```
$ go test -v -bench=.  | prettybench
benchmark                                               iter              time/iter       bytes alloc              allocs
---------                                               ----              ---------       -----------              ------
BenchmarkDedup/withMap____________1-1_________-4    24120418            48.90 ns/op            8 B/op         1 allocs/op
BenchmarkDedup/withSlice__________1-1_________-4   141905514             8.43 ns/op            0 B/op         0 allocs/op
BenchmarkDedup/withBest___________1-1_________-4   133997004             8.77 ns/op            0 B/op         0 allocs/op
BenchmarkDedup/withMap___________10-10________-4     2641770           453.00 ns/op          304 B/op         8 allocs/op
BenchmarkDedup/withSlice_________10-10________-4    32163962            34.20 ns/op            0 B/op         0 allocs/op
BenchmarkDedup/withBest__________10-10________-4    33589612            36.60 ns/op            0 B/op         0 allocs/op
BenchmarkDedup/withMap__________100-100_______-4      147038          8015.00 ns/op         6203 B/op        27 allocs/op
BenchmarkDedup/withSlice________100-100_______-4     3641140           315.00 ns/op            0 B/op         0 allocs/op
BenchmarkDedup/withBest_________100-100_______-4     3614636           295.00 ns/op            0 B/op         0 allocs/op
BenchmarkDedup/withMap_________1000-1000______-4       17374         68439.00 ns/op        51399 B/op        71 allocs/op
BenchmarkDedup/withSlice_______1000-1000______-4      232448          5083.00 ns/op            0 B/op         0 allocs/op
BenchmarkDedup/withBest________1000-1000______-4      395924          2912.00 ns/op            0 B/op         0 allocs/op
BenchmarkDedup/withMap________10000-10000_____-4        1779        653592.00 ns/op       644594 B/op       302 allocs/op
BenchmarkDedup/withSlice______10000-10000_____-4       13440         88416.00 ns/op            0 B/op         0 allocs/op
BenchmarkDedup/withBest_______10000-10000_____-4       14128         87053.00 ns/op            0 B/op         0 allocs/op
BenchmarkDedup/withMap_______100000-100000____-4         138       8634563.00 ns/op      8690895 B/op      2391 allocs/op
BenchmarkDedup/withSlice_____100000-100000____-4        1188        994715.00 ns/op            0 B/op         0 allocs/op
BenchmarkDedup/withBest______100000-100000____-4        1200        985550.00 ns/op            0 B/op         0 allocs/op
BenchmarkDedup/withMap_____10000000-10000000__-4           1    1562777417.00 ns/op    765453080 B/op    251072 allocs/op
BenchmarkDedup/withSlice___10000000-10000000__-4           4     263950640.00 ns/op            0 B/op         0 allocs/op
BenchmarkDedup/withBest____10000000-10000000__-4           4     259640983.00 ns/op            0 B/op         0 allocs/op
BenchmarkDedup/withMap____100000000-100000000_-4           1   20871837757.00 ns/op   9290520352 B/op   2457520 allocs/op
BenchmarkDedup/withSlice__100000000-100000000_-4           1    4611359207.00 ns/op            0 B/op         0 allocs/op
BenchmarkDedup/withBest___100000000-100000000_-4           1    4476460807.00 ns/op            0 B/op         0 allocs/op
BenchmarkDedup/withMap_________1000-100_______-4      135344          9792.00 ns/op         5457 B/op        27 allocs/op
BenchmarkDedup/withSlice_______1000-100_______-4      251731          4435.00 ns/op        16384 B/op         1 allocs/op
BenchmarkDedup/withBest________1000-100_______-4      262458          4228.00 ns/op        16384 B/op         1 allocs/op
BenchmarkDedup/withMap______1000000-100_______-4      116809          9913.00 ns/op         5419 B/op        25 allocs/op
BenchmarkDedup/withSlice____1000000-100_______-4         424       2686605.00 ns/op     15228933 B/op         1 allocs/op
BenchmarkDedup/withBest_____1000000-100_______-4      117105         10059.00 ns/op         5421 B/op        25 allocs/op
BenchmarkDedup/withMap__________100-1000______-4       26851         44487.00 ns/op        29987 B/op        37 allocs/op
BenchmarkDedup/withSlice________100-1000______-4      544766          2086.00 ns/op            0 B/op         0 allocs/op
BenchmarkDedup/withBest_________100-1000______-4      548635          2026.00 ns/op            0 B/op         0 allocs/op
BenchmarkDedup/withMap__________100-1000000___-4          33      36228986.00 ns/op     53197316 B/op        65 allocs/op
BenchmarkDedup/withSlice________100-1000000___-4         506       2304789.00 ns/op            0 B/op         0 allocs/op
BenchmarkDedup/withBest_________100-1000000___-4         516       2301701.00 ns/op            0 B/op         0 allocs/op
ok      test/d/duplicate    91.888s
```

Within those results you can find the one case where the map is more efficient than the slice and the branching helps. In practical terms this case happens when `max(list)` is 100d time bigger than `len(list)`. This happens because the algorithm cannot work in place and must allocate a slice of length equal to `max(list)`

```
BenchmarkDedup/withMap______1000000-100_______-4      116809          9913.00 ns/op         5419 B/op        25 allocs/op
BenchmarkDedup/withSlice____1000000-100_______-4         424       2686605.00 ns/op     15228933 B/op         1 allocs/op
BenchmarkDedup/withBest_____1000000-100_______-4      117105         10059.00 ns/op         5421 B/op        25 allocs/op
```